# What is the best way to create a perl project in 2023

Tags: perl

Few years ago, to start a project, like a module to be available via CPAN, I used Dist:Zilla and few plugins, perl critic, perl tidy, nyt proof, test::more, etc.

Now I'd like to create a simple project -- a parser for a specific base64 encoded message, it should contain a constructor to return an object with few methods and maybe some constants. Maybe a command line tool.

I just don't know how to start a project from scratch anymore.

I imagine my package will be stored in lib/ directory, I should add a Readme, t/ for tests, etc.

How should I start? Should I use `Module::Build` and create a basic `Build.PL` or there are more easier/interessant ways to do it on 2023?

And how about code linting, formatting, testing? is there something new or relevant to check or should I continue with the good old tools?

Comment: If you plan to distribute it, all you really need is `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` and to store your project properly in the `lib` directory as you mention. As well as making a `Makefile.PL`.

Comment: All the development tools you listed are still good, although ```Test2``` is supplanting ```Test```. ```Test2``` has improved testing, and, importantly, also a forward-looking approach to handling stability along with the inevitable evolution of test suites.

Comment: See also: https://blogs.perl.org/users/neilb/2016/04/the-perl-toolchain-developing-your-module.html, and https://perlmaven.com/setup-github-actions, https://www.perl.com/article/how-to-upload-a-script-to-cpan/, and https://youtu.be/JsZw8P_PCUg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a module, that might be something like [Module::Starter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Starter) (people have their own favorites). You've already used dzil, so you could just use that again. It sounds like you already done the same things that we are doing today, so just do that again.

Note that Module::Build is no longer part of the Perl standard library. I prefer that my projects rely only on the standard library unless I have a really good reason to do it differently.